# Using an electric field to rip apart a nucleus

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

Can we use an electric field to rip apart a nucleus? . Let's take 3He which is a very stable isotope but unfortunately not commonly found. And let's assume we have placed an 3He inside a spherical box negatively charged.

The box will attract the protons and because it is spherical this means whatever the orientation of the nucleus the protons will be accelerated to opposite directions.

We will need a very strong electric field to overcome the pion exchange between the protons and the neutron and the protons.

Can we build somethink like that and if not how much theoretically strong must be the electric field to achieve something like this?

Comment: Have you done a back of the envelope calculation of the relative strengths of electric and the strong force inside a nucleus? That yields an estimate of the field needed. Then you need to build an apparatus that won’t rip its atoms apart...

Comment: Related: [Could a strong enough electric field tear a hydrogen atom apart?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/384241/could-a-strong-enough-electric-field-tear-a-hydrogen-atom-apar), [Can electromagnetic fields be used to deconstruct and reconstruct atoms?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44007/can-electromagnetic-fields-be-used-to-deconstruct-and-reconstruct-atoms)

Comment: Jon OK but the protons must accelerate in different direction and since their distance is pretty small some fm then the force would be approximately the same if the electric field is not strong enough.

Comment: Emilio Pissanty I'm talking about construction and deconstruction of nuclei not atoms that is why I said it is an ion.

Comment: @ArtOfElectronics ... which is why I said "Related" instead of "duplicate".

Comment: It is not related by any means. Atoms and nuclei have different physics

Comment: They absolutely are related, the point of linking "related" answers is so you can see if a partial answer (or at least useful information) already exists on the cite.

Comment: If the box and its charge are spherically symmetric, the net force exerted on any charge at any  point inside the spherical shell is zero. As such, it can't be used to pull apart anything.

Comment: Are you talking about a static (DC) electric field or an oscillating field (AC)? The former is practically impossible, but the latter happens with gamma rays all the time.

Comment: @KFGauss - I’m not sure that is exactly the best way one should interpret photofission, but if it works for you...

Comment: Since those protons are tightly bound in the nucleus, in spite of their like charges, the point is to get an estimate of the force needed to rip them apart.

Comment: @Jon Custer, if you are disturbed, then know that I mean to (equivalently) ask whether OP is interested in an electrostatic or photon-driven process.

Answer (score 2):

Due to Newton's shell theorem, the electric field in any uniformly charged shell is zero. Disregarding that, lets say there is some external field where the nucleus is. Such a field would likely be uniform on such a small scale. Since the external field is being applied by an external force, the external field has no divergence where the charge is. That means that if you had a closed surface there, like a sphere, there'd be no net electric flux going through it. As such, the electric field won't be able to rip the nucleus apart, the best it can do is distort it.

Comment: I might say "distort" rather than "compress" in the last sentence..  The nucleus can't be uniformly pushed inwards by an external field for the same reason it can't be pulled uniformly outwards.

Comment: Good point. I've corrected that.

Answer (score 2):

It appears quite impossible to induce fission with an electrostatic field, but gamma rays can actually induce fission in fissionable elements. The reaction known as photofission. See for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photofission.

Answer (score 0):

The concepts have to be clear. Nuclei belong to the quantum mechanical regime, as you yourself acknowledge with :

> to overcome the pion exchange between the protons and the neutron and the protons.

In the quantum regime there is no meaning to "ripping apart" if not expressed as particle exchanges , analogous to the pion exchange rough model for the binding of the nucleus. The energies needed  for this have to be larger than the [binding energies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy) , i.e. order of MeV. Thus the particle exchanged in order to "rip" the nucleus has to have order of MeV energy.

As you are talking of electric fields , the QM particle that exchanges electromagnetic forces is the photon. If you [look at the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum) you will see that this is in the range of gamma rays.

The interaction of an electric field with solid matter, is through the exchange of photons, in this case gamma rays.  This is not an energy range that can be reached to build up electric fields using solid state matter. So  as the answer of my2cts says gamma rays can split up a nucleus.